# Multiple commands produce Parse.bundle

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, cocoapods

Xcode 11.4
Default build system

When trying to archive app using Parse and Parse/FacebookUtils integrated via Cocoapods, I get this build error.

```
Multiple commands produce '<removed>/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Parse.bundle':
1) Target 'Parse-Parse' has create directory command with output '<removed>/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Parse.bundle'
2) Target 'Parse.default-FacebookUtils-Parse' has create directory command with output '<removed>/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Parse.bundle'
```

Parse and Parse/FacebookUtils are version 1.18.0.

Comment: Hi, I notice that you have already opened an [identical issue in the iOS SDK repo](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/1505) which was the correct thing to do in this case. Please refrain from cross-posting as it can waste the time of maintainers.

Comment: I personally think this is fine here, the GiHub repo is not another Stack Overflow question so this isn't a duplicate and even if some of the maintainers of that repo monitor these questions, that doesn't mean that the audiences are the same - another Stack Overflow user who is not monitoring the SDK may have something useful to contribute here, especially since that issue is still not resolved.